# Remove partial string in Shell Script

Tags: shell, string-parsing

How can I remove price from following data in Shell Script? I am printing labels and don't want to show price.

**Input:**

```
Order: 12
Name: Raj K
ABC Inc
123 Main St
Edison NJ

1 Printer - $50.09
Router - $30.00
2 AirPrint - $56.10
```

**Output**

```
Order: 12
Name: Raj K
ABC Inc
123 Main St
Edison NJ

1 Printer
Router
2 AirPrint
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What tools do you have (sed/awk/perl/bash/...), are the prices always exactly like that, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was using few pattern match in sed but no luck. The shell is bash. I  think, I can use perl in the shell script as well, if there is an easy way to do it.

Comment: Please include the things you tried in your question. This will allow people to tell you where you got it wrong and/or how you can do it better. You'll learn more that way.

Comment: The solution below given by Tim works with sed. I was using wrong pattern matches. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed:

```
sed '/ *- *\$[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\{2\}/s///' file
```

<sup>This has been updated in response to Glenn's comment below.</sup>

Comment: You could also take advantage of sed's use of an empty regex re-using the previous one: `sed '/ \+- \+\$[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\{2\}/s///'`

Comment: @glennjackman B.A.  I had no idea that existed.  Edited per your recommendation.